# What is the difference between 時に and 時は

Tags: grammar, particle-に, particle-は

> 昨日雨が降っていた時**に**、私は家にいました。
>
> 昨日雨が降っていた時**は**、私は家にいました。

How do these two sentences differ in meaning? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is really much difference between the two sentences.

昨日雨が降っていた時に "**at** the time it was raining".

昨日雨が降っていた時は "**As for** the time it was raining"

In the second sentence "the time it was raining" is introduced as a topic so it is expcted that the listener already has some knowledge that this event happened.

The は in the second sentence could also be seen as a contrastive marker. i.e I was at home  **at the time it was raining** but I was out for the rest of the time. Either way, I don't think it really changes the meaning in these examples.

Perhaps a native speaker can see more of a change in nuance.